# Pandas: read_json Changes Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `json` file that I'm trying to read into Pandas.  The file looks like this:

```
{"0": {"a": 0, "b": "some_text", "c": "other_text"},
 "1": {"a": 1, "b": "some_text1", "c": "other_text1"},
 "2": {"a": 2, "b": "some_text2", "c": "other_text2"}}
```

When I do:

```
df = pd.read_json("my_file.json")
df = df.transpose()
df.head()
```

I see:

```
            a      b         c
        0   0   some_text   other_text   
        1   1   some_text1  other_text1
        10  10  some_text2  other_text2
```

So the dataframe's index and column `a` have somehow gotten mangled in the process.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: By default, it treats the first column as the index. You can do reset_index to reset the index

Comment: I think the problem was introduced when you saved the DataFrame. You can always do `set_index('a')` to fix it.

Comment: Could you provide its version? I'm not able to reproduce this behavior. (pandas=0.23.4, python=3.6.6)

Comment: @mad_ @coldspeed Thanks!  However, my json keys and the `a` column were changed.  If you look at the 3rd entry in my json file, the key is `"2"` and the value associated with `"a"` is 2 but both get changed to 10...

Comment: @vhcandido Python 2.7.14, pandas 0.19

Comment: @bclayman I've created a conda environment with the provided versions but I'm still unable to reproduce it. The file is loaded by pandas without any alteration, even when I type `"a":10` in the last row the content stays the same and its index is 2.